# Nginx and Munin via CGI, no CSS, no graphs

Tags: nginx, munin

I'm new to Munin and Nginx. I've installed and configured Munin and created a Nginx server block.
I can see the index page generated by munin, listing the different nodes. But when I click on a host to see the graphs, the only thing I get is an HTML page without CSS and without graphs. More precisely, there's the same HTML code in the webpage, the CSS and even in favicon.ico. And no graphs are loaded (I have no 404 for example).

I followed [this tutorial](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI).

Here is my Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name munin.armagnac.[masked].com;

    location ^~ /cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph/ {
        access_log off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph)(.*);
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fcgi-graph.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /etc/munin/static/;
    }

    location / {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/munin)(.*);
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fcgi-html.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have no errors and nothing in the logs.

As said above, a node page is almost blank:

[image: node webpage]

There's no CSS because any other resource is just the same HTML page:

[image: css and favicon are html]

Again, there's nothing in the logs and the HTML and Graphs CGIs are working fine. But I don't know where is the configuration problem, eg. on the Nginx side or in the Munin side.

OS: Ubuntu Server 15.04

Comment: Your main page renders correctly? If you compare the contents of the main page and the above (I see in the screenshot, it's the hosts page), you will recognize it's actually the same. the resources just don't load because the base path changed. This means that the CGI doesn't know the path you are asking for. This should be the Param PATH_INFO (`/` vs `/localdomain/localhost.localdomain`), as documented in https://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/reference/munin-cgi-html.html, but it doesn't seem to work for some reason, on my machine neither

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue while setting up munin.

*edit*

What I did was:

1. Install spawn-fcgi from source
2. Setup a startup script for the spawn-fcgi
3. Make sure the location `/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/` and `/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html/` are forwarded to the respective spawned fcgi processes.

My vhost, the relevant section:

```
location /munin {
#    alias /var/cache/munin/www;
    index index.html;
#    include /etc/nginx/php.conf;
#    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;                                
}

location ^~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/ {
#   if ($uri ~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/([^/]*)) { set $path $1; }
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph)(.*);
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fastcgi-munin-graph.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location  ^~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html/ {
#   if ($uri ~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html/([^/]*)) { set $path $1; }
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-html)(.*);
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fastcgi-munin-html.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Do try my setup over here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/670535/munin-nginx-no-dynazoom-into-graphs/745265#745265 where the init script is also included.

Works fine for me till today

Comment: please, try to put the important parts to the answer body. Link-only answers are not allowed.

Comment: [Why link-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out. Still learning here :p

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. What helped me was changing

```
  location /munin/ {
    alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
    index index.html;
  }
```

to be

```
  location ^~ /munin/ {
    alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
    index index.html;
  }
```

Notice that `^~`. After changing this and reloading Nginx all css and images started loading correctly.